# Is it possible to train deep learning agent to pass a multiple-choice exam?

Tags: deep-learning

Is it possible to train an agent to take and pass a multiple-choice exam based on a digital version of a textbook for some area of study or curriculum? What would be involved in implementing this and how long would it take, for someone familiar with deep learning?

Comment: There are a variety of problems to solve here; however, since we've seen IBM's Watson win at Jeopardy, I'm certain it's possible. Probably not practical, but certainly possible.

I'll let someone more familiar with implementations answer your question about the resources (including time) necessary though.

Comment: Is there a reason why not?

Comment: Can you give some example? What kind of exam?

Comment: @kenorb Multiple choice

Comment: Matty - the answer to your first question is yes or no, depending on the area of study. The other questions should be separate as they are very variable depending on scenario. So I have flagged as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

There are programs that do this today, for some values of "curriculum" and "exam".  It does not even require deep learning; a simpler information retrieval algorithm and some rules for composition work and [achieve high scores on machine graded essays.](http://www.popsci.com/article/technology/essay-writing-machine-made-fool-other-machines)

For human graders, there is research on [automatically generating essay-length text responses to queries in a certain domain.](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jmoore/course-reads/nlg/McKeown85.pdf)

Both linked applications are rule-based rather than based in deep-learning.  I'd guess that a deep-learning approach would be much less efficient (in computer resources) in producing comparable results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be possible with a lot of questions to learn from and only from a certain topic. Just watch what IBM was capable of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFR3lOm_xhE very impressive!